# Unable to start services in Centos 7 with error "Authorization not available" even as root user

Tags: centos, docker, centos7, service, authorization

I am not able to start services for the following Centos 7 server

```
[root@myserver home]# uname -r
3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64
[root@myserver home]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

I first realised there was a problem when I observed that docker was down, so I ran the following as root

```
[root@myserver home]# systemctl start docker
 Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for 
 more information.
 Failed to start docker.service: Connection timed out
 See system logs and 'systemctl status docker.service' for details.
[root@myserver home]# systemctl status docker.service
 ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
 Docs: https://docs.docker.com
```

I then ran

```
 [root@myserver home]# systemctl | grep -i fail
 ● firewalld.service                          loaded failed     failed      firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
 ● plymouth-start.service                     loaded failed     failed      Show Plymouth Boot Screen
 ● polkit.service                             loaded failed     failed      Authorization Manager
 ● systemd-machined.service                   loaded failed     failed      Virtual Machine and Container Registration Service
 ● tuned.service                              loaded failed     failed      Dynamic System Tuning Daemon
```

Also

```
 [root@myserver home]# systemctl status polkit.service
 ● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2021-02-04 11:14:54 GMT; 5h 45min ago
      Docs: man:polkit(8)
   Process: 7932 ExecStart=/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Main PID: 7932 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

  Feb 04 11:13:23 myserver.com systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
  Feb 04 11:13:48 myserver.com polkitd[7932]: Started polkitd version 0.112
  Feb 04 11:14:54 myserver.com systemd[1]: polkit.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
  Feb 04 11:14:54 myserver.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Authorization Manager.
  Feb 04 11:14:54 myserver.com systemd[1]: Unit polkit.service entered failed state.
  Feb 04 11:14:54 myserver.com systemd[1]: polkit.service failed.
```

I am not aware of any updates made to the server. I think these problems began after an unplanned reboot, but I can't establish the reason for the reboot. Why would starting the Authorization Manager time out? Does anyone have any suggestions for further investigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I issued a

```
[root@myserver home]# reboot
```

command and it seems to be working. Before, when I was having the initial problem, I had used

```
[root@myserver home]# shutdown -r now
```

I am curious as to why the difference in the two commands caused my initial problem...

Answer (score 1):

Just document my case, this could help some one

polkit is a policy service that means some other services need it's authorization before executing actions

The problem appears after kvm backup restore
guest VM uses centos 7
if I tried to start or restart any service like network or sshd the system reboots after showing this message for secons

`Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.`

In my case polkit was complaining about dbus error like

`Failed to connect to system bus: Connection refused`

journalctl -b -p err

I found that missing disk casus issues with dbus

Solution was easy **remove the missing disk from fstab**

Also I found similar problem here https://www.thegeekdiary.com/authorization-not-available-check-if-polkit-service-is-running-or-see-debug-message-for-more-information-centos-rhel-7-ssh-service-error/